# Unity bouncing ball with the same height and falling speed control

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity

how do I create a bouncing ball in unity that bounces to the same height and that I can make it fall quicker or slower? A person told me to use:

`heightVector * |sin(time * speed)|`

but I don't know where to insert it. I'm really noob at these things. Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula is correct.
The `heightVector` is the maximum height of your ball. For example if it's `(0,10)`, then it means that your ball will go 10 meters high.
The `time` is simply a timer.
The `speed` is the speed of your ball.

However, I recommend to multiply the speed by `Time.deltaTime` to make the bounce frame-rate independent.

Let's start writing code.
`heightVector` and `speed` have no complexity. Just create two public fields and you're done!

```
class Bouncer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10;
    public Vector2 HeightVector = new Vector2(0,10);
}
```

To create a timer, you need a `float` variable. Then you need to add `Time.deltaTime` to it on every `Update` call.

```
class Bouncer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10;
    public Vector2 HeightVector = new Vector2(0,10);

    float timer;
    void Update()
    {
         timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Congrats! you now have your timer!

Now you are really close to end. You just need calculate the current position of the ball and apply it to its transform.

```
class Bouncer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10;
    public Vector3 HeightVector = new Vector3(0,10);

    float timer;
    void Update()
    {
         timer += Time.deltaTime;

         Vector3 currentPosition = HeightVector * Mathf.Abs(timer * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

         transform.position = currentPosition;
    }
}
```

Now you need to attach the Bouncer script to your ball and your ball should start bouncing!

**Edit:**
If you want the ball to keep its original position and bounce from there, you need to keep the original position and append the calculated position to it:

```
class Bouncer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10;
    public Vector3 HeightVector = new Vector3(0,10);
    Vector3 originalPosition;
    float timer;

    void Start()
    {
        originalPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
         timer += Time.deltaTime;

         Vector3 currentPosition = HeightVector * Mathf.Abs(timer * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

         transform.position = originalPosition + currentPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have another question, if there is no other object where the ball could bounce, the ball will fall?

Comment: @DavidMeléndez No. The ball doesn't use physics. Its position is calculated with a constant formula regardless of the environment.

Comment: I tried the script but the ball is really fast, also the original ball location is at -40,50,100 so i tried to edit new vector3 to (0,50) but the ball returned to 0,0,0

Comment: Is it possible to make the ball to fall if there is no object when the ball reaches its minimum height vector?

Comment: @DavidMeléndez Not with this formula. If you want to use physics, you can use [Physics Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html). Just set `Bounciness` to `1`.

Comment: I did, but the while the ball is bouncing, the ball increases height on each bounce. What should I do?

Comment: @DavidMeléndez from [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html): `The same logic applies to the bounciness model. Nvidia PhysX doesn’t guarantee perfect energy conservation due to various simulation details such as position correction. So for example when the bounciness value of an object affected by gravity is 1 and is colliding with ground that has bounciness 1 expect the object to reach at higher positions than then initial one.`